# jQuery I can't access to getAttribute attribute in e.currentTarget

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, target

I am using an arrow function with setTimeout and am having issues accessing the `getAttribute` of the clicked element.

What could be the cause of this issue?

```js
let myTimeout;
const time = 2000;

$(document).on("touchstart", "figure img", (e) => {
  myTimeout = setTimeout(function(e) {
    var figure = e.currentTarget;
    var img = figure.querySelector("img");
    var src = img.getAttribute("src");
    console.log("src>" + src);
    console.log("PRESS DELAY");
  }, time);
});
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" />
  </figure>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: probably the parameter you specified in settimeout that shadows the param you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues are that

1. your event listener is setting `e` to `img` already (since you did `"figure img"`, so when you do `figure = e.currentTarget; img = figure.querySelector('img')` it's trying to find a child img of the img, which doesn't make sense.
2. the function in `setTimeout` is shadowing the `e` variable, so `e` will be undefined inside of that function.

It should look like this:

```js
let myTimeout;
const time = 2000;

$(document).on("touchstart", "figure img", (e) => {
  myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    var img = e.target;
    var src = img.getAttribute("src");
    console.log("src>" + src);
    console.log("PRESS DELAY");
  }, time);
});
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" />
  </figure>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm stupid. Very sorry. I learn a lot with your help.